# Is there a close equivalent to Russian saying "Chem dalshe v les tem bolshe drov"

Tags: proverbs, russian

So far I found only one reference which is not helpful

https://www.quora.com/What-does-the-Russian-saying-the-deeper-into-the-forest-the-fatter-the-partisans-mean

Comment: In the same ballpark is the expression 'they are like wine left undisturbed on its lees/dregs' from [Zephaniah 1:12; BibleHub](https://biblehub.com/zephaniah/1-12.htm): _New International Version_
At that time I will search Jerusalem with lamps and punish those who are complacent, _who are like wine left on its dregs_, ... //  _Christian Standard Bible_
And at that time I will search Jerusalem with lamps and punish those who settle down comfortably, .... Though from what I've just seen on the film 'Defiance' showing Resistance life in Eastern Europe, forest life was far from being a picnic.

Comment: Please add the literal translation to the question and also your own description of what it means especially with the nuances it has or implies when used in the original language.

Answer (score 0):

The farther into the forest, the more firewood. = 
As the days grow longer, the storms are stronger.
тык
https://translate.enacademic.com/the%20storms%20are%20stronger/en/ru/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are two interrelated meanings here. One can be captured  by the phase "out of the woods" (complexity [of the situation] as a trap in and by itself)  and the second "As the days grow longer, the storms are stronger" (difficulties of any operation typically increase as your goals expand you go and you can be stack in the tar pit as the result).

BTW in the second sense it is opposite to the Russian saying "appetite comes with the meal"

Yes, Andorian is absolutely correct as for the second  meaning of this  saying:

**As the days grow longer, the storms are stronger**

It capture the "reaction part" very well, although the action part ("the farther/deeper into the forest" is the "personal action" part) is missing. But this is probably the best one can find.

Thanks a lot !!!

P.S. From Quora comment that is relevant in this context

> **But what it actually means, is the further you dig into some issue,
>   the worse side effects you get**, the worse collateral and the heavier
>   the side information you dig out. It can also imply that, the deeper
>   you dig into something, **the more myths, lies and stereotypes** you are
>   bound to meet.

Comment: There is a Russian idiom "Nalomat' drov" which might be related and has a meaning  "to make the situation worse by compounding your own mistakes",  so the exact meaning of “Chem dalshe v les tem bolshe drov” might well be closer to "the more complex the situation is, the more chances to make it worse by compounding your own mistakes." 

Which is closer to "add insult to injury"